# Does every operation you write in a spark job performed in a spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

1. lets say for the operation 
   val a = 12 + 4, or something simple.
   Will it still be distributed by the driver into cluster ?
2. lets say I have a map , say Map[String,String] (very large say 1000000 key value pairs)(hypothetical assumption)

Now when I do get*("something"),
Will this be distributed across the cluster to get that value?
If not , then what is the use of spark if it doesn't computes simple task together?

3. How is the number of tasks determined by spark also number of job determined ?
4. If there is a stream and some action is perform for each batch. Is it so that for each batch new job is created?

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. No, This is still a driver side compute.
2. If you create the map in a Driver program then it remains on driver. If you try access a key then it would simply lookup on the map you created on driver memory and return you back the value.
   If you create a RDD out of the collection ([Reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections)) , and if you run any transformation then it will be run on Spark cluster.
3. Number of partitions usually corresponds to the number of tasks. You can explicitly tell how many partitions you want when you parallelize the collection ( like the map in your case)
4. Yes, there will be a job created for action performed on each batch.